# Mark an email as read when read on Gmail app

Tags: sync, gmail, lg-g3

Sometimes I read my emails on my lg g3 but every time I open my mac I have those emails as unread. In other words, it seems that the gmail app does not mark the emails as read on the Google's server ...

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: Solved! I just deleted the app's data and it worked as someone mentioned [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/K3_Cx7XJUmU)

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, you should write your own answer and mark it as the correct one.